# Bootstrap Toggle Sidebar Dropdown Icon

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

On the sidebar navigation of my site, I've got dropdown menu's working. However, I want the icon to change between pointing right `<i class="icon-angle-right"></i>` and pointing down `<i class="icon-angle-down"></i>` depending on which state the code is in (closed or opened).

Here's the code that repeats itself for each menu:

```
<!-- USER -->
<li class="nav-header">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#userMenu">
    <font color="#333333">User</font> <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul style="list-style: none;" class="collapse in" id="userMenu">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i> Messages <span class="badge badge-info">4</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cogs"></i> Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-comment"></i> Shoutbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Staff List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-flag"></i> My Infractions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> Rules &amp; Regulations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<!-- RADIO DJ -->
<li class="nav-header">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#radioDJMenu">
    <font color="#34CCFF">Radio DJ</font> <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul style="list-style: none;" class="collapse" id="radioDJMenu">
        <li><a href="#">Information &amp; Stats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DJ Says</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Request Line</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Banned Songs</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Updated 2018***

You can do this using jQuery..

```
$('[data-toggle=collapse]').click(function(){
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("icon-angle-right icon-angle-down");
});
```

I update the Bootply from your last question about the collapse menu..
[Bootstrap 3.x Toggle Icon Demo](http://bootply.com/61710)

---

The concept is similar for **Bootstrap 4**, except `in` is now `show`, and there are no longer glyphicons: https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/wS2OYMzQdr

Comment: neither the toggle icon or dropdown menu closing is working for me. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong either.